# jQuery text filterbox that looks like Google Docs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can this be done in jQuery? Any reference?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about jQuery Chosen plugin - http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/?

Comment: Brilliant plugin. Dunno if it solves the OP's question, but it solves one I haven't even asked yet!